# Why does CSVREAD not work as expected when it is supposed to read the column names from the csv file?

Tags: h2

According to the [H2 documentation](https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvread) for CSVREAD

> If the column names are specified (a list of column names separated with the fieldSeparator), those are used, otherwise (or if they are set to NULL) the first line of the file is interpreted as the column names.

I'd expect reading the csv file

```
id,name,label,origin,destination,length
81,foobar,,19,11,27.4
```

like this

```
insert into route select * from csvread ('routes.csv',null,'charset=UTF-8')
```

would work. However, actually a `JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` is thrown, saying `NULL not allowed for column "ORIGIN"` and indicating error code `23502`.

If I explicitly add the column names to the insert statement like so,

```
insert into route (id,name,label,origin,destination,length) select * from csvread ('routes.csv',null,'charset=UTF-8')
```

it works fine. However, I'd prefer not to repeat myself - following the DRY principle :)

Using version 2.1.212.

Comment: It's good coding practice to _always_ specify the target columns of an INSERT - regardless where the data comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CSVREAD` function produces a virtual table. Its column names can be specified in parameters or in the CSV file.

`INSERT` command with a query doesn't map column names from this query with column names of target table, it uses their ordinal positions instead. Value from the first column of the query is inserted into first column specified in insert column list or into first column of target table if insert column list isn't specified, the second is inserted into second column, and so on.

You can omit insert column list only if your table was defined with the same columns in the same order as in the source query (is your case in the CSV file). If your table has columns declared in different order or it has some additional columns, you need to specify this list.